# Smarty substr string skip first characters

Tags: character, smarty, substr, skip

The variable `$siteroot` contains a string that looks like:

http://www.example.nl/folder/

To get the part http://www.example.nl/ you use:

`{$siteroot|substr:0:22}`

But i want to skip this part and return /folder/

The length of the folder is unknown.

Comment: check my answer, you don't have to pass static position

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{$siteroot|substr:22}
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

```
{assign var="bar_at" value=$siteroot|strpos:"nl/"}
{$siteroot|substr:$bar_at+2}
```

Comment: I found a answer on another question looking similar to your answer, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: And what if its not a nl domain?

Comment: @MaartenKuilman you just need to get the position of first instance of ,in this case "nl/" and print all values after that. I used this in one of my projects and it worked for all instances

Comment: @MaartenKuilman assign that domain to variable and pass that value to strpos